# How to send a message from server to client freely when using python diesel?

Tags: python

When a client send a message to a server, the server can send back a massage simultaneously.

```
'''Simple echo server.
'''
from diesel import Application, Service, until_eol, send

def hi_server(addr):
    while 1:
        inp = until_eol()
        if inp.strip() == "quit":
            break
        send("you said %s" % inp)

app = Application()
app.add_service(Service(hi_server, 8013))
app.run()
```

if i want to send a message from a server to a client when no requesting from the client, how to do it?

Comment: Are you asking how you can send a message to a client from the server without the client initiating a request?

Comment: Yes. Although I can do it use a special client and fire, but it's too complicated.

Comment: I don't think you understand the concepts of a client - server setup. Typically the Client is the one initiating the request where as the server is listening/waiting for a request. In your case you need two servers acting as both a client and a server.